# JSF passing params to another view

Tags: jsf, parameters

I have a page, where there is a table with a link to page for edit item

```
<h:dataTable rendered="#{cc.attrs.data.size() ne 0}" border="1" value="#{cc.attrs.data}" var="req">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Тема</f:facet>
            <h:link outcome="/pages/request" value="#{req.topic}">
                <f:param name="reqId" value="#{req.id}"/>
            </h:link>
        </h:column>
...
```

The page for edit:

```
<f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="reqId" value="#{requests.currentRequest}" converter="#{reqParamConverter}"/>
    </f:metadata>
    <center>
        <h:panelGroup id="requestContent" style="text-align: left;display:block;max-width:450px;">
            <h:outputText value="Автор: #{requests.currentRequest.customer.email}"/><br/>
... other fields
```

and my converter is:

```
@Named("reqParamConverter")
@RequestScoped
public class RequestParamConverter implements Converter{

@Inject
private RequestBoundary boundary;

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    ... //null checks
    Long id=Long.valueOf(value);
    Request request= boundary.getRequest(id);
    return request;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
   ... // null checks
    Long id = ((Request) value).getId();
    String result= (id!=null)? String.valueOf(id):null;
    return result;
}
}
```

and backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "requests")
@RequestScoped
public class Requests {
private Request currentRequest;
... getters setters
```

the problem is `currentRequest` is null and in my converter in method `getAsString`, the `Object value` parameter is null;
as a result on page for edit all fields are empty
I don't see what's wrong there, I also tried @FacesConverter but as I read from BalusC article, I can't use @Inject

UPD: I solve this by adding in getter method for currentRequest field:
check if currentRequest is null then I get parameter from request URL (because url still have ?reqId=.. parameter) and then get Request from boundary:

```
public Request getCurrentRequest() {
    if(currentRequest==null) {
       String param=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("reqId");
       if(param!=null && !param.isEmpty()){
       Long id=Long.valueOf(param);
       currentRequest=boundary.getRequest(id);
       }
       else {
           System.out.println("Request parameter is null");
       }
    }
    return currentRequest;
}
```

But I don't think that logic in getter is a good idea :o

Comment: I want to add: this works fine on my localhost environment but don't work on the other computer environment(also localhost) in both cases I use Glassfish+Derby

Comment: I don't understand why it uses getAsString,  as I saw, all logs from getAsObject was ignored

Comment: You've confirmed the parameter is being transmitted properly from the source page and the injection of `RequestBoundary` is happening properly?

Comment: 1) I've added logs in getAsString and getAsObject methods and logs only from getAsString shows that RequestBoundary injected properly.

Comment: 2) on localhost it works fine and parameter passes from page to page and converted but on another computer there is a problem

Comment: I've updated question with my quick fix

Comment: '@RequestScoped' in the converter is from enterprise.context package and '@RequestScoped' in the backing bean is from faces.context. I tried this annotation in backing bean also from enterprise.context package and there  was the same result